# How to add the header in autogenerated bindings code by qdbusxml2cpp?

Tags: qt, qtdbus, qdbusxml2cpp

$qdbusxml2cpp -v -c CustomIf -p customif.h:customif.cpp org.item.custom.xml

org.item.custom.xml

```
<node>
<interface name="org.pace.custom">
<method name="Send_Custom_Msg">
<arg name="msg" type="a(ii)" direction="in"/>
<annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" value="Message"/>
</method>
<signal name="LateEvent">
<arg name="eventkind" type="s" direction="out"/>
</signal>
</interface>
</node>
```

How to add the header - message.h in the generated adaptor customif.h? I don't want to add manually into it as #include "message.h", but actually want the qdbusxml2cpp to add the inclusion.

Comment: $ qdbusxml2cpp -c  CustomIfAdaptor -a -i  customifadaptor.h:customifadaptor.cpp org.pace.custom.xml In this command, where to add message.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following option:

```
-i <filename> Add #include to the output
```

So, this would be the corresponding command:

```
qdbusxml2cpp -v -i message.h -c CustomIf -p customif.h:customif.cpp org.item.custom.xml
```